# CSS Grid with 2 rows, 4 columns, 7 items. How to center the second row?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have 7 dynamic content to display in my page.
Here is my code for the content :

```css
<?php if ($n==1) { ?>
<div class="large-12 columns">
 
 <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4 partner-grid">
<?php  } ?>
  <li>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="th people-thumb">
    <span class="partners-thumb pt<?php echo $n; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $pimg; ?>" /></span>
    <h2 class="th-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
   </a>
  </li>
<?php if ($n==8) { ?>
 </ul>
 </div>
<?php  } ?>
<?php
  $n++;
 endwhile;
?>
```

Now it runs OK but the second row, which contains 3 items is justified to the left (as it should be).

Is there anyway to center the 3 second row items, while keeping the gap and the size like this?

Image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XghyR.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap maybe. 
Use some css to deal with border and Background colors

```
<div class="row no-gutters d-flex justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="bg-primary text-center m-1 text-white">a</div></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="bg-primary text-center m-1 text-white">a</div></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="bg-primary text-center m-1 text-white">a</div></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="bg-primary text-center m-1 text-white">a</div></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="bg-primary text-center m-1 text-white">a</div></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="bg-primary text-center m-1 text-white">a</div></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="bg-primary text-center m-1 text-white">a</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "one one two two three three four four" ". five five six six seven seven .";
    width: 80vw;
    grid-gap: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: orangered;
}

.grid > div{
    border: solid dodgerblue 3px;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    background: #fff;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(1){grid-area:one}
.grid > div:nth-child(2){grid-area:two}
.grid > div:nth-child(3){grid-area:three}
.grid > div:nth-child(4){grid-area:four}
.grid > div:nth-child(5){grid-area:five}
.grid > div:nth-child(6){grid-area:six}
.grid > div:nth-child(7){grid-area:seven}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `flex-wrap` and `justify-content` like in the **snippet** below - use the width that suits you... i used `120px` for this example:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```